# access file system iOS device using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, fileapi

I am developing a iOS app using Phonegap. This application should be able to download files from Internet, storing them into a directory previously created in the device.
I have done the same thing for Android target, and my code works properly. It creates the directory in the phone, download and save files. 
In iOS my code doesn't work. I've tried to search solutions in the web, without results.

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("device ready");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.name);
    console.log(fileSystem.root.name);              
    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;
    directoryEntry.getDirectory("myDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail);
}

function onDirectorySuccess(parent) {
    console.log(parent);
    window.localStorage.setItem("directory_path",parent.toURL()+'/');
}

function onDirectoryFail(error) {
    alert("Unable to create new directory: " + error.code);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

In the console I can see this output:

```
2014-04-14 17:30:11.338 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-04-14 17:30:11.350 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-04-14 17:30:11.470 XXXXXX[1511:60b] [CDVTimer][file] 4.680991ms
2014-04-14 17:30:11.613 XXXXXX[1511:60b] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 140.942991ms
2014-04-14 17:30:11.615 XXXXXX[1511:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 149.509966ms
2014-04-14 17:30:11.640 XXXXXX[1511:60b] active
2014-04-14 17:30:13.902 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-04-14 17:30:14.334 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
2014-04-14 17:30:14.335 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-04-14 17:30:14.718 XXXXXX[1511:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/3A5B82C4-3787-442F-858F-E0850F4A6338/XXXXXX.app/www/home.html
```